# Getting the position of an element given an index and order

Tags: ravendb

I have a map/reduce index containing something like `{ Id, Name, Points}` (`Points` is a sum)

I can easily query and order by descending `Points` to get a list of elements.

Now, in a specific part of my application, I need to get a single value with the position of one of the documents.

For example, if Jack has 10 points, John has 15 points and Jane has 30 points, Jane's position would be 0.

Is there a way to do this that is more efficient than iterating through the results until I find the one I'm interested in?

Answer (score -1):

Sure, 
Let us assume that you want the 7th item in the list.

```
session.Query<YourIndex.Result, YourIndex>()
 .Where( ... )
 .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Points)
 .Skip(7)
 .Take(1)
  .ToList();
```

Note that you shouldn't be doing deep paging.

Comment: Oren, I actually want the opposite: given an item, determine its position in a sorted list.

Answer (score -3):

In T-Sql

select top 1 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Points DESC) as RowN, Id, Name, Points from map